# How does one hide selected faces in 3d View while in UV editor?

Tags: uv, 3d-view

Is it possible to make blender hide all the selected faces on the 3D model when you are in the UV edit mode? Or perhaps create a script that does? It's hard to see what you select in the UV editor and not having the "keep mesh in sync" option activated. What I can do so far is to hide the faces by unchecking the option in the 3D view toolbar but you still get the edges highlighted which makes the seams hard to see. What I is for the model to appear as it would look in edit mode with solid shading and nothing selected, that is with standard black edges and seams visible. How can this be achieved?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you mean by "UV edit mode". Are you asking about the UV editor screen layout, with the UV editor window on the left, and the 3D window on the right, or are you referring to just the UV editor window iteslf? Also, what type of 3D model are you referring to? I think the questions should have at least a screenshot, and perhaps a copy of the blend file posted to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or a similar hosting site, with the link posted here,

Comment: But what's the problem in having option  `UV and Edit mode mesh selection sync` checked ?

Comment: Mr Zak, The problem is that in the "keep in sync mode" Blender moves several vertc if you move one,island select mode does not work etc. Blender has two modes for something that only needs one mode. I only work with sync off all the time so its very frustrating to have to switch modes constantly to be able to just see what is selected.

Comment: I think that is not currently possible. I'm not completely understanding what you are proposing, but there seems to be some good points.  Till now, the only option is " UV and Edit mode mesh selection sync". (you can "fake" island selection with ctrl+L)